# SSL on cart in x.myshopify.com

Tags: shopify

We have a frontend website that forwards users to our shopify shopping cart for purchasing of our product. Our frontend website needs to be ssl for various reasons. However, the x.myshopify.com/cart page is not ssl. There is a very big pop up that comes up warning the user they are going from a secured site to an unsecured site.

We need the ability to have https on the cart in myshopify.com. How do we do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you go directly to the checkout.. you get seamless HTTPS transitions. Do you really need to mess with the cart or can you just proceed from your site to checkout?

Comment: We need to give users the ability to select quantity.

Comment: That is easy... here is the recipe. http://www.shopify.com/technology/4849802-new-feature-cart-permalinks

Comment: That does not work because the user still can't add of remove quantity. The quantity in that example is governed by what ever number we put in the url string.

Comment: Yes, but your user selects the variant ID and quantity on your HTTPS site, and you just call the URL for them. So it does what you originally asked for.